# Page edit auto-creates blank revision and editor

Tags: revisions

I'm in the process of migrating an existing WP site to Cloudways and every time I try to edit a page the editor is blank and there's a brand new blank revision auto-saved. (Thankfully not published.)

The "current revision" is still set to revision that contains content... so it's been a real pain copying the data from the database and pasting it back into the editor... just to change or edit existing content.

All plugins are currently disabled and the behavior still persists. :/

Comment: Do you use a default theme?

Comment: I was using a custom theme, the switched to twenty seventeen, then to another custom theme and finally to twenty sixteen... with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the transition from `utf8` encoded databases to `utf8mb4`.

Apparently the editor was getting a silent error and defaulted to dropping the transaction.

---

**The Solution:** Recently Wordpress has started switching to using `utf-8mb4`, so most people probably need to change their charset `<meta charset="UTF-8"` ***to*** `<meta charset="UTF-8mb4">`. Very old and out of date blogs may need to convert from `latin1`.

Most of the time your meta tag is filled in using `bloginfo( "charset" )`, which is [pulled straight from your database](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/), specifically your `wp_options` table.

> ‘charset‘ – Displays the “Encoding for pages and feeds” set in Settings > Reading. This data is retrieved from the “blog_charset” record in the wp_options table. Note: this parameter always echoes “UTF-8”, which is the default encoding of WordPress.

Therefore you can open your database and change the field, if you'd like. From `UTF-8` to `UTF-8MB4`.

Or you can just hack it into your theme like so...

`<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ) ?>`**mb4**`">`